# Order model by field with choices

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to order models in a Django app using a field that has predefined choices.  I can sort alphabetically, but since the choices are the days of the week, that doesn't quite match what I need.  Here's the model:

```
class Slot( models.Model ):

    DAY_CHOICES = (
        ('SUN', 'Sunday'),
        ('MON', 'Monday'),
        ('TUE', 'Tuesday'),
        ('WED', 'Wednesday'),
        ('THU', 'Thursday'),
        ('FRI', 'Friday'),
        ('SAT', 'Saturday'),
    )

    day = models.CharField( max_length=3, choices=DAY_CHOICES )
    start = models.TimeField()
    end = models.TimeField()
    template = models.ForeignKey( Template )
```

And here's the inline that's pulling the model into an admin view:

```
class SlotInline( admin.TabularInline ):
    model = Slot
    ordering = ('day','start',)
```

I know I could probably use an integer as the stored value, but is there a general way to impose a custom sort order on a field with choices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from the last paragraph of https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#field-choices:

> But if you find yourself hacking choices to be dynamic, you're
>   probably better off using a proper database table with a ForeignKey.
>   choices is meant for static data that doesn't change much, if ever.

So I'd say the answer is no and you'd be better of with a separate Day model with a field for ordering

```
class Day(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    ordering = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['ordering']
```

Even though it feels like overkill for 7 items!

Answer (score 2):

You should store the data as an integer (eg 0 = Sunday), and use the choices to map that integer to the day. Then sorting is simple.

Comment: I pointed out that approach in the question - I'm looking for a more general way to order by choices. It works in this case, but what happens when the sort order needs to change? I shouldn't need to modify my models just because I want to display it differently.

Answer (score 0):

If you were writing your own view rather than using the admin view, you could potentially do the ordering in raw SQL.  I've done this before in Oracle with something like:

```
ORDER BY decode(day, 'SUN', 0, 'MON', 1 )
```

I don't know how you'd fit that in with `QuerySet.order_by()` - maybe you'd need to use `QuerySet.raw()` to do the query with direct SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should look at this library: https://github.com/bigjason/django-choices

I don't know any basic to do such thing, unlike fields where you can specify a function name, you can't do that in ordering. The only special thing you can do is to specify get_ordering.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `extra`, although the implementation might not be graceful and needs tweaking for complex query and different choices:

```
# generate 'WHEN foo THEN bar's
switch = ' '.join("WHEN '{}' THEN {}".format(x[0],i) for i,x in enumerate(Slot.DAY_CHOICES))
# basic queryset
Slot.objects.extra(select={'day_index':'CASE day {} END'.format(switch)}).order_by('day_index', 'start')
```